# What is VB.Net equivalent of Collections class used in iText7 Java sample?

Tags: java, vb.net, itext7

I try to write a little `VB.Net` program to read text and position from PDF input page.

I have found an example on GitHub at [testarea/itext7/ExtractPositionalText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/extract/ExtractPositionalText.java)

This example is written in `Java` and I have migrated all lines except this one

```
return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)));
```

What is `VB.Net` equivalent ?

How can I replace this Java code using VB.net ?

Comment: [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a Java class from the java.util package. The method [Collections.unmodifiableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) returns an unmodifiable view of the specified set.

Comment: @life888888: I search a `Collections` class which name ends with `s` and that contains an `unmodifiableSet` method. Your comment doesn't help me to solve my question !

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I have found that this `Java` code can be replaced by `Collection` without `s`.

I have tested my extract text and location program with following lines

```
Dim collection As New List(Of EventType)
collection.Add(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
Return collection
```

For those that search to write a VB.Net program to extract text and location from PDF file using `iText7` (version: 7.2.5), the complete code is following

A class that contains rectangle and text

```vbnet
    Public Class RectAndText
        Public rect As Rectangle 'iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle
        Public sText As String

        Public Sub New(rect As Rectangle, text As String)
            Me.rect = rect
            Me.sText = text
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The event listener

```vbnet
    Public Class XEventListener
        Implements IEventListener

        Private textWithRectangleList As New List(Of RectAndText)

        Public Function getResultantTextWithPosition() As List(Of RectAndText)
            Return textWithRectangleList
        End Function

        Private Sub RenderText(t As TextRenderInfo)
            If t.GetText().Trim().Length() = 0 Then Return

            Dim ascent As LineSegment = t.GetAscentLine()
            Dim descent As LineSegment = t.GetDescentLine()

            Dim initX As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(0)
            Dim initY As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(1)
            Dim endX As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(0)
            Dim endY As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(1)

            Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(initX, initY, endX - initX, endY - initY)

            textWithRectangleList.Add(New RectAndText(rect, t.GetText()))
        End Sub

        Public Sub EventOccurred(data As IEventData, type As EventType) Implements IEventListener.EventOccurred
            Dim datax As TextRenderInfo = data
            Call RenderText(datax)
        End Sub

        Public Function GetSupportedEvents() As ICollection(Of EventType) Implements IEventListener.GetSupportedEvents
            Dim collection As New List(Of EventType)
            collection.Add(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
            Return collection
        End Function
    End Class
```

and the extract page code in main program

```vbnet
    Dim listener As New XEventListener()
    Dim processor As New PdfCanvasProcessor(listener)
    processor.ProcessPageContent(page)

    Dim result = listener.getResultantTextWithPosition()
    For Each x As RectAndText In result
        Console.WriteLine("Text: " & x.sText)    
        Console.WriteLine("Location: " & x.rect.ToString())    
    Next
```